# I want to create xml in order to execute my classes

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

I have created a TestNG XML File, which I have called multiple classes. My concern is that I want to execute my test cases on all classes which I have arranged from top to bottom like below. However some of the bottom cases depend on upper cases, and whenever I run my XML File it selects the classes randomly. How would I go  about doing this?

Type - 1

```
{
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite3">
  <test name="Test3" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.RegistrationTestCase"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.LoginTestCase"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.AddNetworkTestCase"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.AddDevicesTestCase"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.CreateSsidTestCase"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.DeleteDevicesTestCase"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.accountCheck.About"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.accountCheck.AccountManage"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testRunEnd.GetTotalStatus"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testRunEnd.SendReport"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test3 -->
</suite> <!-- Suite3 -->
}
```

Type - 2

```
{
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite1">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test One" >
    <classes>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.RegistrationTestCase"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.LoginTestCase"/> 
    </classes>
 </test> <!-- Test -->
 <test thread-count="5" name="Test Two" >
   <classes>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.AddNetworkTestCase"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.AddDevicesTestCase"/>
         <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.CreateSsidTestCase"/>
   </classes>
 </test> <!-- Test -->
 <test thread-count="5" name="Test Three"  >
     <classes>
          <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.UrlFilterTestCase"/>
          <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.DeleteDomainTestCase"/>
          <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.DeleteDevicesTestCase"/>
      </classes>
     </test> <!-- Test -->
     <test thread-count="5" name="Test Four" >
         <classes>
                 <class name="com.netgearInsight.testReports.AddDataVLAN"/>
                 <class name="com.netgearInsight.accountCheck.AccountManage"/>
                 <class name="com.netgearInsight.accountCheck.About"/>
                 <class name="com.netgearInsight.accountCheck.ChangePassword"/>
          </classes>
          </test> <!-- Test --> 
         <test thread-count="5" name="Test Five">
             <classes>
                   <class name="com.netgearInsight.testRunEnd.GetTotalStatus"/>
                   <class name="com.netgearInsight.testRunEnd.SendReport"/>
             </classes>
             </test> <!-- Test -->`enter code here`
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

  }
```

Comment: Do you see any deviation in execution of _Type - 1_ with **preserve-order="true"**

Comment: Which version of TestNG are you using? Type - 1 works for me.

Comment: @DebanjanB  No, I didn't see any deviation in type one

Comment: @RSingh I am using 6.14.0.2018 TestNg